# How do I change select to input text while checkbox is checked?

Tags: javascript, html

It's my first contact with js so please don't hate me
I have something like this:

```js
function Zmiana(isChecked) {
  document.getElementById('test').type = 'text';
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <select id="test" name="producent" class="dropdown-select">
    <option value="Apple">Apple</option>
    <option value="Samsung">Samsung</option>
    <option value="Lenovo">Lenovo</option>
  </select> <br>
</div>
```

But it doesn't work

Comment: You haven't shown a checkbox in the code you posted. and you haven't set up any event handler to invoke your callback function.

Comment: would the change from `select` to `text` be reversible? IE: if the user checks and then unchecks should the element be a `select` field once again?#

Comment: Changing a `<select>` to `<select type="text">` doesn't make sense

Comment: @ScottMarcus i have add it now

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius yes, something like this will be great

Comment: Don't try and convert an existing element into another; instead set a `disabled` attribute/property on the element you want to remove, and simply show/hide an `<input>` or the `<select>`. The showing and hiding is easily enough done with CSS. Also: where is your check-box `<input>`?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. A couple of comments and questions. 1. You mention a checkbox, but you don't include the checkbox anywhere. Can you clarify this or add how/where you are using the checkbox? 2. `...('test').type` select doesn't normally have a type attribute (unless you set it). Input has a `type` attribute. I think it's possible that you want the `value` attribute instead of the type attribute, but even then your code won't work because 'text' doesn't match a value in your select box.

Comment: Both your select and your checkbox have the same id of `test`.  **Ids are unique and should not be repeated within a single DOM**.

Comment: You also might want to check out using a plain input element (type=text) and use a datalist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't be changing the `select` into a textbox. Instead, you'll have both a `select` and a textbox. The checkbox will simply determine which is shown.

Also, your `select` should include a first choice that is not considered valid so that you don't get a submitted value that the user didn't choose.

```css
.hidden { display:none; }
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="check">Check to enter text directly
<div class="dropdown">
   <select id="test" name="producent" class="dropdown-select">
        <option value="">--- Choose ---</option>
        <option value="Apple">Apple</option>
        <option value="Samsung">Samsung</option>
        <option value="Lenovo">Lenovo</option>
   </select>
   <input id="data" class="hidden">
</div>

<script>
  let text = document.getElementById('data');
  let check = document.getElementById("check");
  let select = document.getElementById("test");

  // You must set up your function to handle the
  // click event of the checkbox
  check.addEventListener("click", Zmiana);
  
  function Zmiana(){
    // Add or remvoe the hidden class based on 
    // whether it's already in use
    select.classList.toggle("hidden");
    text.classList.toggle("hidden");
  }    
</script>
```

Comment: Also the `<input id="data" class="hidden">` should include `type="text"` attribute

Comment: @user3647971 `text` is the default value of the `type` attribute on an `input` - - it's not necessary to add it if you want a textbox. You can see that if you run my code.

Comment: @ScottMarcus do you have any idea why select is not hidding when i click on the checkbox? Just input is showing

Comment: @KrzysztofRadzi If you use the code I've shown, it will work. If it's not working you must be doing something different than what I've shown. Did you notice the CSS `.hidden` class that must be added?